# 3D object from CINEMA4D has glowing edge in After Effect

Tags: after-effects, 3d, cinema4d

I have a composition of a video and a 3d object on it, coming from CINEMA 4D. There is a ~1 pixel wide glowing artefact around the edge of the imported 3d object. What can be the reason and how can I fix it?

[image: the mattress is the 3D object, the light edge is clearly visible, especially on the lower right edge]

Comment: On the screenshot, the preview quality is set to draft, but the final quality has the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at how AE is interpreting the footage (right-click it in the project and look for **Interpret Footage>Main**). Specifically look at how it is interpreting the alpha channel, it could be interpreting a straight alpha channel as pre-multiplied or the alpha channel might be pre-multiplied with another colour instead of black). Have a go at switching between alpha modes, or try setting the pre-multiplied colour to white instead of black.

If that fails you'll need to de-fringe the layer in your comp. A simple choker effect would do the trick.